# How to Redirect a POST to another server as POST (play framework)

Tags: scala, playframework

`Redirect("http://localhost:8002/processrequest")` after doing this localhost:8002 got request as GET Request not POST.

How to redirect this request as a POST request to server localhost:8002?

Answer (score 1):

Feature you expect from Play is not supported not because of Play framework HTTP layer implementation, but because of HTTP Specification for [Redirections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#principle):

> When browsers receive a redirect, they immediately load the new URL provided in the ***Location*** header.

It is not intended to change a request method.